What is the solution for the "No adapter attached; skipping layout" error in displaying data in RecyclerView?
I was encountering an error from the logcat "No adapter attached; skipping layout" whenever I navigate in the fragment_claimed.xml where the claimed items will be shown. Any idea on how to fix this? Is there anything wrong with my java, xml or php code?
fragment_claimed.xml:

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.kITa.ClaimedActivity">
Top toolbar with icons -->
Main Bottom Navigation Bar -->

First row with Guide, Logo, and Search icons -->

Guide Icon -->

Logo Image -->

Search Icon -->


Second row with Bottom Navigation icons -->

        <ImageButton

android:id="@+id/nav_lost"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:padding="8dp"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:src="@drawable/ic_lost"
android:background="@color/white"
android:contentDescription="lostIcon"
/>
        <ImageButton

android:id="@+id/nav_found"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:padding="8dp"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:src="@drawable/ic_found"
android:background="@color/white"
android:contentDescription="foundIcon"
app:tint="@color/green"
/>
        <ImageButton

android:id="@+id/nav_chat"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:padding="8dp"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:src="@drawable/ic_chat"
android:background="@color/white"
android:contentDescription="chatIcon"/>
        <ImageButton

android:id="@+id/nav_notifications"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:padding="8dp"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:src="@drawable/ic_notification"
android:background="@color/white"
android:contentDescription="notifIcon"/>
        <ImageButton

android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:padding="8dp"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
android:background="@color/white"
android:contentDescription="profileIcon"/>


Main Content Container -->

    <TextView

android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
android:text="Claimed Items"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textColor="@color/green"
android:textSize="24sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

android:id="@+id/claimedItemsRecycleView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/textView"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

layout_claimeditem.xml (layout of the card):


<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:clickable="true"
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
app:contentPadding="5dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
    <LinearLayout

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView

android:id="@+id/itemImg"
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:src="@drawable/ic_uploadphoto" />

        <LinearLayout

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginStart="10dp">
            <TextView

android:id="@+id/itemName"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Name of Item"
android:textColor="@color/green"
android:textSize="25dp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView

android:id="@+id/location"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location"
android:text="Location"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:textColor="@color/green" />


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


ClaimedActivity.java:

package com.example.kITa;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class ClaimedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView claimedItemsRecycleView;
private ClaimedItemAdapter claimedItemAdapter;
private List claimedItemsList;
private static final String URL = "https://10.0.2.2/lost_found_db/get_claimed_items.php";
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_claimed);
claimedItemsRecycleView = findViewById(R.id.claimedItemsRecycleView);
claimedItemsRecycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
Initializing the list and adapter
claimedItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
claimedItemAdapter = new ClaimedItemAdapter(this, claimedItemsList);
Setting the adapter early to avoid the warning
claimedItemsRecycleView.setAdapter(claimedItemAdapter);
fetchClaimedItems();
}
private void fetchClaimedItems() {
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
response -> {
try {
JSONArray itemsArray = new JSONArray(response);
for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject itemObject = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
String itemName = itemObject.getString("item_name");
String locationFound = itemObject.getString("location_found");
ClaimedItem claimedItem = new ClaimedItem(itemName, locationFound);
claimedItemsList.add(claimedItem);
}
Log.d("ClaimedActivity", "Items fetched: " + claimedItemsList.size());
Notify the adapter of data changes
claimedItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Log.e("ClaimedActivity", "JSON parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
}
},
error -> Log.e("ClaimedActivity", "Volley error: " + error.getMessage())
);
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
}

ClaimedItemAdapter.java

package com.example.kITa;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.List;
public class ClaimedItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClaimedItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private List claimedItemsList;
public ClaimedItemAdapter(Context context, List claimedItemsList) {
this.context = context;
this.claimedItemsList = claimedItemsList;
}
@NonNull
@Override

public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_claimeditem, parent, false);
return new ViewHolder(view);
}
@Override

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
ClaimedItem claimedItem = claimedItemsList.get(position);
holder.itemName.setText(claimedItem.getItemName());
holder.location.setText(claimedItem.getLocationFound());
Log.d("ClaimedItemAdapter", "Binding item: " + claimedItem.getItemName());
}
@Override

public int getItemCount() {
return claimedItemsList.size();
}
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public TextView itemName, location;
public ImageView itemImg;
public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
super(itemView);
itemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.location);
itemImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImg);
}
}
}

ClaimedItem.java:

package com.example.kITa;
public class ClaimedItem {
private String itemName;
private String locationFound;
public ClaimedItem(String itemName, String locationFound) {
this.itemName = itemName;
this.locationFound = locationFound;
}
public String getItemName() {
return itemName;
}
public String getLocationFound() {
return locationFound;
}
}

get_claimed_items.php:

connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

Fetch claimed items
$sql = "SELECT item_name, location_found FROM reported_items WHERE status='Claimed' AND remark='Approved' ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$claimedItems = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $claimedItems[] = $row;
    }
}

echo json_encode($claimedItems);

$conn->close();
?>

but unfortunatelly, the same problem occurs. I stuck for about 2 days to that problem. Hopefully you could help me in showing the claimed items in the claimed activity / fragment_claimed.
